# Resharper NUnit test actions hiding refactoring actions

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nunit, resharper

I'm using Resharper in Visual Studio 2019

In test classes, the usual refactoring actions in the margin are replaced by buttons to run the tests, e.g.:
[test class in Visual Studio showing test buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMe4k.png)

This is annoying when I want to do one of the usual refactoring actions, e.g.: rename the file to the name of the class.

If I comment out the [Test] attribute I can see it:
[test class in Visual Studio showing refactoring actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QFzv.png),

This isn't practicable if there are lots of test methods. Is there another way to access the usual actions?

Thanks,

Rob.